# Just want to put up image directory to excel but keep getting NullpointException with following error

Tags: java, apache-poi

What im trying to do here is to find .txt file, draw some text out, asign it to its respective cell on excel and then from same folder, bring image directories and asign it to next sheet of same excel workbook.

The first part went well with method FoldFil but the image directory part is throwing error as given below. Ive checked by printing out of the l1l etc got well asigned as string directory and it works. *No error is shown if i delete the InputStream.close() to OutputSteram.close() portion of the imgSource method* and I cant seem to find what the problem is.
Just side not, it would be big help if sb can help me with somehow writing less code for the switch case down there.

```
public class BringFolderFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private JPanel contentPane;
    static BringFolderFrame frame;
    //--------------------------------------------------Main
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    frame = new BringFolderFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    //------------------------------------------constructor class below**
    public BringFolderFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 451, 248);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(SystemColor.textHighlight);
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        JButton btnFolderSelector = new JButton("Select Folder");
        panel.add(btnFolderSelector,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        btnFolderSelector.addActionListener(this);
        setResizable(false);
    }//-------------------------------------------------------------------all thats seen is frame is above this--
    //--------------------------------------------------------------image directory to excel for excess to next frame
    public void imgSource(File gvnfold) throws IOException {        
        FileInputStream inputStream=new FileInputStream("src/main/java/test.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        XSSFSheet sheet2=workbook.getSheetAt(1);                    //2nd sheet 
        String filenm="a";
        File[] folder = gvnfold.listFiles();
        for (File file : folder) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                filenm=file.getName().toLowerCase();
                System.out.println(filenm);
                //---------------------putting image directory to respective excel cell by switch case
                
                switch (filenm) {
                case "1_1_1.jpg":XSSFCell l1l=sheet2.getRow(1).getCell(1);  l1l.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
                case "1_1_2.jpg":XSSFCell l1c=sheet2.getRow(2).getCell(1);  l1c.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
                case "1_1_3.jpg":XSSFCell l1r=sheet2.getRow(3).getCell(1);  l1r.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
                case "1_2_1.jpg":XSSFCell l2l=sheet2.getRow(4).getCell(1);  l2l.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
                case "1_2_2.jpg":XSSFCell l2c=sheet2.getRow(5).getCell(1);  l2c.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
                case "1_2_3.jpg":XSSFCell l2r=sheet2.getRow(6).getCell(1);  l2r.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
                case "1_3_1.jpg":XSSFCell l3l=sheet2.getRow(7).getCell(1);  l3l.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
                case "1_3_2.jpg":XSSFCell l3c=sheet2.getRow(8).getCell(1);  l3c.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
                case "1_3_3.jpg":XSSFCell l3r=sheet2.getRow(9).getCell(1);  l3r.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
                case "1_4_1.jpg":XSSFCell l4l=sheet2.getRow(10).getCell(1); l4l.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
                case "1_4_2.jpg":XSSFCell l4c=sheet2.getRow(11).getCell(1); l4c.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
                case "1_4_3.jpg":XSSFCell l4r=sheet2.getRow(12).getCell(1); l4r.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
                case "1_5_1.jpg":XSSFCell l5l=sheet2.getRow(13).getCell(1); l5l.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
                case "1_5_2.jpg":XSSFCell l5c=sheet2.getRow(14).getCell(1); l5c.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
                case "1_5_3.jpg":XSSFCell l5r=sheet2.getRow(15).getCell(1); l5r.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
                
                case "2_1_1.jpg":XSSFCell r1l=sheet2.getRow(16).getCell(1); r1l.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
                case "2_1_2.jpg":XSSFCell r1c=sheet2.getRow(17).getCell(1); r1c.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
                case "2_1_3.jpg":XSSFCell r1r=sheet2.getRow(18).getCell(1); r1r.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
                case "2_2_1.jpg":XSSFCell r2l=sheet2.getRow(19).getCell(1); r2l.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
                case "2_2_2.jpg":XSSFCell r2c=sheet2.getRow(20).getCell(1); r2c.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
                case "2_2_3.jpg":XSSFCell r2r=sheet2.getRow(21).getCell(1); r2r.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
                case "2_3_1.jpg":XSSFCell r3l=sheet2.getRow(22).getCell(1); r3l.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
                case "2_3_2.jpg":XSSFCell r3c=sheet2.getRow(23).getCell(1); r3c.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
                case "2_3_3.jpg":XSSFCell r3r=sheet2.getRow(24).getCell(1); r3r.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
                case "2_4_1.jpg":XSSFCell r4l=sheet2.getRow(25).getCell(1); r4l.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
                case "2_4_2.jpg":XSSFCell r4c=sheet2.getRow(26).getCell(1); r4c.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
                case "2_4_3.jpg":XSSFCell r4r=sheet2.getRow(27).getCell(1); r4r.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
                case "2_5_1.jpg":XSSFCell r5l=sheet2.getRow(28).getCell(1); r5l.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
                case "2_5_2.jpg":XSSFCell r5c=sheet2.getRow(29).getCell(1); r5c.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
                case "2_5_3.jpg":XSSFCell r5r=sheet2.getRow(30).getCell(1); r5r.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
                
                }
            }
        }
        inputStream.close();
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("src/main/java/test.xlsx");
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        workbook.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------method that does ---folder>file.txt>info-->excel 
    
    public void foldFil(File gvnfold) throws IOException {  
        //-------------------------------------------------------------finds .txt file and reader it -------------
        String filenm="a";
        File[] folder = gvnfold.listFiles();
        for (File file : folder) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                filenm=file.getName().toUpperCase();
                if (filenm.contains(".TXT")){
                    filenm.toLowerCase();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        File personalfile = new File(gvnfold+"/"+filenm);
        String name="";     String parent="";   String age="";      String number="";
        String school="";   String address="";  String email="";    String line;
        int linecount=0;    Scanner sc = null;
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------saves name etc from txt in respective strings
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(personalfile);
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                linecount+=1;
                line = sc.nextLine();
                if(linecount==4) {name=line;}       //--name
                if(linecount==6) {parent=line;}     //--parent
                if(linecount==8) {age=line;}        //--parent
                if(linecount==10) {number=line;}    //--number
                if(linecount==14) {school=line;}    //--school
                if(linecount==16) {address=line;}   //--address
                if(linecount==18) {email=line;}     //--email
            }
         
            FileInputStream InputStream=new FileInputStream("src/main/java/test.xlsx");
            XSSFWorkbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook(InputStream);
            //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------sends name etc string to its rest excel cells
            XSSFSheet sheet1=workbook.getSheetAt(0);        //1st sheet 
            XSSFCell cellname=sheet1.getRow(1).getCell(1);  //name
            cellname.setCellValue(name);
            XSSFCell cellparent=sheet1.getRow(2).getCell(1);//parent
            cellparent.setCellValue(parent);
            XSSFCell cellage=sheet1.getRow(3).getCell(1);   //age
            cellage.setCellValue(age);
            XSSFCell cellnum=sheet1.getRow(4).getCell(1);   //number
            cellnum.setCellValue(number);
            XSSFCell cellschool=sheet1.getRow(6).getCell(1);//school
            cellschool.setCellValue(school);
            XSSFCell celladd=sheet1.getRow(7).getCell(1);   //address
            celladd.setCellValue(address);
            XSSFCell celle=sheet1.getRow(8).getCell(1);     //email
            celle.setCellValue(email);
            
            //---------------------------------------------------clearing and closing inputstream and writing the changes
            InputStream.close();
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("src/main/java/test.xlsx");
            workbook.write(outputStream);
            workbook.close();
            outputStream.close();
        
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
            {e.printStackTrace();}
                  finally {if (sc != null) sc.close();} 
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------actionListner overrides
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
        JFileChooser fileChoose=new JFileChooser();
        fileChoose.setCurrentDirectory(new File("D:\\colz\\java"));
        fileChoose.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        int resp =fileChoose.showOpenDialog(null);
        if(resp==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            
            File file=new File(fileChoose.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
            try {imgSource(file);} catch (IOException e2) {e2.printStackTrace();}
            try {foldFil(file);} catch (IOException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}
            //new ScanAnlyFrame().setVisible(true);
            //new turtleWork(file);
            frame.dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

the following is the error. and its annoyingly long too.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow.getCell(int)" because the return value of "org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.getRow(int)" is null
    at BringFolderFrame.imgSource(BringFolderFrame.java:97)
    at BringFolderFrame.actionPerformed(BringFolderFrame.java:185)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6626)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3389)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5001)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: What exact code line is `BringFolderFrame.java:97`? Means code line 97 in BringFolderFrame.java.

Comment: thats the last line of the switch case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Exception is:

```
... java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow.getCell(int)" because the return value of "org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.getRow(int)" is null
    at BringFolderFrame.imgSource(BringFolderFrame.java:97)
```

and the code line 97 in BringFolderFrame.java is

```
case "2_5_3.jpg":XSSFCell r5r=sheet2.getRow(30).getCell(1); r5r.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
```

then `sheet2.getRow(30)` returns `null`. That can be if that row is not stored in the Excel sheet. Then `sheet2.getRow(30).getCell(1)` throws that `NullPointerException` because, of course, `null.getCell(1)` cannot work.

In Excel sheet storage only used rows are stored. Unused rows, which are totally empty, are not stored.

Thats why, as documented,  [Sheet.getRow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getRow-int-) might return `null` for rows which are not stored.

The same is for cells in rows. There also only used cells are stored and [Row.getCell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getCell-int-) might return `null` if that cell is not stored.

So writing code like

```
...
case "1_1_1.jpg":XSSFCell l1l=sheet2.getRow(1).getCell(1);  l1l.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
...
case "2_5_3.jpg":XSSFCell r5r=sheet2.getRow(30).getCell(1); r5r.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);  break;
...
```

is always error prone.

Always `null` checks are needed. So something like

```
...
XSSFRow row = null;
XSSFCell cell= null;
...
case "1_1_1.jpg":
 row = sheet2.getRow(1); if (row == null) row = sheet2.createRow(1);
 cell = row.getCell(1); if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(1);
 cell.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);
 break;
...
case "2_5_3.jpg":
 row = sheet2.getRow(30); if (row == null) row = sheet2.createRow(30);
 cell = row.getCell(1); if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(1);
 cell.setCellValue(gvnfold+"\\"+filenm);
 break;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, row was not stored in the Excel sheet. I was trying to access a null row. I did correction in my loop so that I don't refer null row.